# Disable android content provider signature permission for debug build

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-contentprovider

For example content provider has signature permission for main build

```
  <provider
        android:name=".com.test.ContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.test.provider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.test.permission" />
```

and signature permission

```
  <permission
        android:name="com.test.permission"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

How to disable this permission for debug build?
Tried to add content provider with the same name but without `android:permission="com.test.permission"` line to AndroidManifest.xml  (debug) without luck

**Upd1:** tried to add `tools:node="remove"` to permission itself, but this doesn't work:

```
   <permission
        tools:node="remove"
        android:name="com.test.permission"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

At the same time `tools:node="remove"` inside content provider removes content provider completely from debug build.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `ContentProvider` permissions, but you may try these options:

**1/** In your debug `AndroidManifest.xml`, use this declaration:

```
<provider
    android:name=".com.test.ContentProvider"
    tools:remove="android:permission" />
```

This will remove the permission in the merge manifest for the debug build

**2/** Define the permission in a strings resources. Define the permission value in the main `strings.xml`, in the debug `strings.xml` leave it blank.

```
main: <string name="permission_name">com.test.permission</string>
debug: <string name="permission_name"></string>
```

Your `provider` tag simply references the string based on build:

```
<provider
    android:name=".com.test.ContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.test.provider"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="@string/permission_name" />
```

Don't know if permission is required or not, these are just some ways to customize your configuration by different builds

Comment: Thanks for reply, unfortunately this solution doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can use build variant-specific manifest files in your Android project. This approach allows you to define different manifest files for different build types

create debug manifest `src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

In your debug-specific manifest, override the provider declaration. Since you want to disable the permission, you don't include the android:permission attribute in this declaration.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<application>
    <provider
        android:name=".com.test.ContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.test.provider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:replace="android:permission" />
</application>
```

You can have additional manifests in directories named after each build variant, like `src/debug` for the debug build and `src/release` for the release build. These manifests only need to include the parts that are different from the base manifest.